# The Node Beginner Book TypeError: Cannot call method 'writeHead' of undefined

Tags: node.js, undefined, typeerror

I just follow **The Node Beginner Book** on http://www.nodebeginner.org/ while I encounder a **TypeError**。 I've searched but no one can solve the error. The error shows as follows

```
D:\delbert\nodejs\proj\requestHandlers.js:7
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
             ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'writeHead' of undefined
    at D:\delbert\nodejs\proj\requestHandlers.js:7:14
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:635:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
```

and the source code:

//---------//
//server.js//
//---------//

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function start(route, handle) {
  function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");

    route(handle, pathname, request, response);
  }

  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
  console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

//--------//
//index.js//
//--------//

```
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./route");
var requestHandlers = require("./requestHandlers");

var handle = {}
handle["/"] = requestHandlers.start();
handle["/start"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/upload"] = requestHandlers.upload;

server.start(router.route, handle);
```

//--------//
//route.js//
//--------//

```
function route(handle, pathname, response) {
  console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
  if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function') {
    handle[pathname](response);
  } else {
    console.log("No request handler found for " + pathname);
    response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("404 Not found");
    response.end();
  }
}

exports.route = route;
```

//------------------//
//requestHandlers.js//
//------------------//

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

function start(response) {
  console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");

  exec("ls -lah", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
    response.write(stdout);
    response.end();
  });
}

function upload(response) {
  console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello Upload");
  response.end();
}

exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;
```

I don't know how the error comes. It stuck there even I paste the code from the book.

I tried [TypeError: Cannot call method 'writeHead' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080271/typeerror-cannot-call-method-writehead-of-undefined) and http://cnodejs.org/topic/4fbca9123a7ec1d151038ac1 but they did not work.

Would you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book does indeed seem to have some errors then.

Here are a couple of errors I spotted right away:

1. `server.start()` calls `route()` like this: `route(handle, pathname, request, response);`, but `route()` is actually defined like this: `function route(handle, pathname, response)`
2. (and most likely the source of your specific error) `index.js` has `handle["/"] = requestHandlers.start();` instead of `handle["/"] = requestHandlers.start;`

Comment: I modified the definition of route function to `function route(handle, pathname, request, response)` in index.js. The start method without `()` is okay. Thank you.

Comment: @Delbert - Did you ever get through the last use case (uploading a .png image file) in the tutorial?  I think I've gone through all the steps but it's not working.  I can post a question but I need someone experienced with this tutorial.  Can you help?